# Memtest86 Test Result

Tags: 22.04, ram, crash, memtest

I am using Ubuntu 22.04, since last week my web browsers (firefox and Chrome) have suffered random crashes. I looked it up on the internet and someone suggested I use memtest86 for hardware issues.
Here is the memtest86 result:

[image: memtest86 result]

The result says failed.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: When the memory fails in a test, I strongly suggest that you replace it.

Comment: Replacing the RAM stick ?

Comment: Yes, I think the computer will continue to crash randomly because of RAM errors, and I think it can be fixed by replacing the RAM stick. - There might be some other cause, for example bad electrical connection, which might be fixed by unplugging and plugging back the RAM stick (which should remove a possible thin layer of oxide).